# Custom Boolean Parameter Binding

Tags: c#, model-binding, asp.net-web-api2

I have a WebApi method, like this one:

```
public string Get([FromUri] SampleInput input)
{
    //do stuff with the input...
    return "ok";
}
```

The input is defined like this:

```
public class SampleInput
{
    // ...other fields
    public bool IsAwesome { get; set; }
}
```

As it is, it works OK: if I pass `&isAwesome=true` in the query string, the parameter is initializes with the value `true`.

My problem is that I'd like to accept both  `&isAwesome=true` and `&isAwesome=1` as `true` values. Currently, the second version will result in `IsAwesome` being `false` in the input model.

---

What I tried, after reading the various blog posts on the subject, was to define an `HttpParameterBinding`:

```
public class BooleanNumericParameterBinding : HttpParameterBinding
{
    private static readonly HashSet<string> TrueValues =
        new HashSet<string>(new[] { "true", "1" }, StringComparer.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase);

    public BooleanNumericParameterBinding(HttpParameterDescriptor descriptor) : base(descriptor)
    {
    }

    public override Task ExecuteBindingAsync(
        ModelMetadataProvider metadataProvider, 
        HttpActionContext actionContext,
        CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        var routeValues = actionContext.ControllerContext.RouteData.Values;

        var value = (routeValues[Descriptor.ParameterName] ?? 0).ToString();

        return Task.FromResult(TrueValues.Contains(value));
    }
}
```

... and register it in *Global.asax.cs*, using:

```
var pb = GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.ParameterBindingRules;
pb.Add(typeof(bool), p => new BooleanNumericParameterBinding(p));
```

and

```
var pb = GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.ParameterBindingRules;
pb.Insert(0, typeof(bool), p => new BooleanNumericParameterBinding(p));
```

None of these worked. My custom `HttpParameterBinding` is not being called and I still get the value `1` translated to `false`.

How can I configure WebAPI to accept the value `1` as `true` for Booleans?

**Edit:** The example I presented is intentionally simplified. I have a lot of input models in my application and they contain many boolean fields that I would like to be handled in the manner described above. If there was just this one field, I would not have resorted to such complex mechanisms.

Comment: I have a workaround suggest, create a readonly property say `IsAwesome1` in `SampleInput` and make `IsAwesome ` as string , set `IsAwesome1` = true only if `IsAwesome ` = `"1"` or `"true"`

Comment: @ArindamNayak There are simply too many fields like the one in my example and that would bloat the code. I thought there was a more elegant way to do it in Web API. I'm reverting to MVC for the moment; I have an `IModelBinder` that does the job well`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Looks like decorating the parameter with the `FromUriAttribute` just skips the parameter binding rules altogether. I made a simple test replacing the `SampleInput` input parameter with a simple `bool`:

```
public string Get([FromUri] bool IsAwesome)
{
    //do stuff with the input...
    return "ok";
}
```

and the boolean rule is still not getting called (`IsAwesome` is coming as `null` when you call `&isAwesome=1`).
As soon as you remove the FromUri attribute:

```
public string Get(bool IsAwesome)
{
    //do stuff with the input...
    return "ok";
}
```

the rule gets called and the parameter correctly bound.
The FromUriAttribute class is sealed, so I think you're pretty much screwed - well, you can always reimplement it and include your alternate boolean binding logic ^_^.